# How to change magento theme on refresh page?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

Have multiple different theme in magento.
Is that possible to change or apply different theme on refresh page or resize browser?
Means there are installed 2 magento theme.
theme1 and theme2
default theme is theme1 but when refresh page its apply theme2
is this possible?
If have knowledge please help me for this customization.

Comment: Help me understand why?  I'm curious about this but I don't understand why you would want it.

Comment: we used 2 different theme for desktop and one for mobile view. so want when user resize browser its automatically get mobile theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme based on the user agent, but not by resize (load a completely new theme need inevitably the reload the entirely page)
[image]